# dot (.) causing alias to break

Tags: bash, shell, linux-mint, alias

I am trying to create an alias for the command -

```
rsync -avh --omit-dir-times --delete --filter='protect .sync' /media/blueray/Data/_Work/ /media/blueray/Data/_CloudYandex/
```

The command I am using to create the alias is -

```
alias by='rsync -avh --omit-dir-times --delete --filter='protect .sync' /media/blueray/Data/_Work/ /media/blueray/Data/_CloudYandex/'
```

The error I am getting while trying to execute the alias is -

```
$ by
unexpected end of filter rule: protect
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at exclude.c(1011) [client=3.1.2]
```

I checked and found that `alias` only took the part before **dot**.

```
$ alias
..
alias by='rsync -avh --omit-dir-times --delete --filter=protect'
.....
```

What can I do to overcome this?

Comment: either change the inner quotes to double quotes or outer quotes to double quotes.

Comment: @Jetchisel Working Now `alias by="rsync -avh --omit-dir-times --delete --filter='protect .sync' /media/ismail/Data/_Work/ /media/ismail/Data/_CloudYandex/"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single quotes pair, they don't nest.

Change the second and third single quotes to double quotes:

```
alias by='rsync -avh --omit-dir-times --delete --filter="protect .sync" /media/blueray/Data/_Work/ /media/blueray/Data/_CloudYandex/'
```

Comment: I was a fool to not notice it. `alias by="rsync -avh --omit-dir-times --delete --filter='protect .sync' /media/ismail/Data/_Work/ /media/ismail/Data/_CloudYandex/"`

Comment: The "protect" hooks onto the first quoted part, because there are no intervening spaces. I would have expected it to try to execute the rest of the line when it created the truncated alias, though, and complain: .sync....: not found.

Comment: It takes 10 minutes to accept. Sorry for the inconvenience.